# Is there a way to loop through cursor faster in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to insert a big amount of data in a table from a file, but the data need to be checked if will be inserted or updated.

My program works like this

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_OR_UPDATE
IS
    [...]

BEGIN

    READ_FROM_FILE_AND_INSERT_ON_SUPPORT_TABLE;

    DECLARE
        CURSOR C1 IS
            SELECT ROWID ROW_ID, A.* FROM SUPPORT_TABLE A;

    BEGIN
        FOR RECORDS IN C1 LOOP
            BEGIN
                SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4, COLUMN5
                INTO   vVARIABLE1, vVARIABLE2, vVARIABLE3, vVARIABLE4, vVARIABLE5
                FROM TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
                WHERE A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
                AND   A.COLUMN2 = B.COLUMN2
                AND   A.COLUMN3 = B.COLUMN3
                AND   A.COLUMN4 = B.COLUMN4
                AND   A.COLUMN1 = RECORDS.COLUMN1
                AND   A.COLUMN3 >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'));

                IF
                    RECORDS.COLUMN1  = vVARIABLE1
                    AND  W1.COLUMN2  = vVARIABLE2
                    AND  W1.COLUMN3  = vVARIABLE3
                    AND  W1.COLUMN4 >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
                THEN
                    UPDATE SUPPORT_TABLE
                    SET STATUS_MESSAGE = 'TO UPDATE',
                    STATUS = 'PROCESSED',
                    WHERE ROWID = RECORDS.ROW_ID;

            EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                UPDATE SUPPORT_TABLE
                SET STATUS_MESSAGE = 'TO INSERT',
                STATUS = 'PROCESSED'
                WHERE ROWID = RECORDS.ROW_ID;
        END LOOP;
    END;
END;
```

The problem is, the performance of the code is very awful. After run by 4 hours it only processed 0.05% is there a way to optimize the process?.

Obs.: The file have 654.000 lines.

Comment: You must use collection instead of cursor to make it faster.

Comment: Form the dataset that should be a source of update as a result of `select` statement, and then use `merge` statement to update your table with the data you've received. This doesn't require loops. Please provide some sample data and desired output for it for someone could provide an answer as a working code.

Comment: which is the table where you need to insert?

Comment: What are the data types of A.COLUMN3 and W1.COLUMN4 ?  Why are you having to play games with converting sydate (a DATE) to a string, then to a number for the comparison?  If the data in those columns represent dates, then they should be data type DATE, and you do straight date comparisons.

Comment: The big question is what is slow?  Is it the SELECT and walking through it? Or is it the UPDATEs? Eliminate the UPDATEs and just walk the cursor and see what happens with performance. That will tell you if it's the SELECT or UPDATE that is slow.

Comment: If you use `ROWID` then you should specify the explicit cursor with `FOR UPDATE`. Otherwise the ROWID may change.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to want a single `MERGE` statement:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_OR_UPDATE
IS
  W1 TABLE1%ROWTYPE; -- Define W1 as something
BEGIN
  READ_FROM_FILE_AND_INSERT_ON_SUPPORT_TABLE;

  MERGE INTO support_table dst
  USING (
    SELECT s.ROWID AS rid,
           a.COLUMN1,
           a.COLUMN2,
           a.COLUMN3,
           a.COLUMN4,
           COLUMN5
    FROM   support_table s
           LEFT OUTER JOIN (
             TABLE1 A
             INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
             ON (   A.COLUMN1 = B.COLUMN1
                AND A.COLUMN2 = B.COLUMN2
                AND A.COLUMN3 = B.COLUMN3
                AND A.COLUMN3 >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
                AND A.COLUMN4 = B.COLUMN4
                )
           )
           ON (A.COLUMN1 = s.COLUMN1)
  ) src
  ON (src.rid = dst.ROWID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET status_message = CASE
                         WHEN src.COLUMN1 IS NOT NULL
                         THEN 'TO UPDATE'
                         ELSE 'TO INSERT'
                         END,
        status         = 'PROCESSED'
    WHERE src.COLUMN1 IS NULL
    OR    (   W1.COLUMN2  = src.COLUMN2
          AND W1.COLUMN3  = src.COLUMN3
          AND W1.COLUMN4 >= TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMMDD'))
          );
END;
/
```

*(Note: this code is untested as no `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT` statements were provided for your sample data nor any expected output so it is unclear what your expected behaviour would be.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=c6685e4750d3a871698b448edce9422e)*

Answer (score 3):

Use Merge for this, it's efficient and covers your needs:

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1 A
USING (SELECT *
         FROM SUPPORT_TABLE) records
   ON (
        RECORDS.COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN1
      )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET <A.COLUMN(S) = records.columns>
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT INTO A VALUES records;
```

(this is pseudo since you haven't specified the destination table neither the table descriptions)